# Is it doable to customize(adding Icons) the expanded menu in android

Tags: android

Is it doable to customize(adding Icons) the expanded menu. Just I want to add an Icon to this expanded menu (go here when we click Icon Menu's "More" menuitem).

Of course there is no direct way to do this. I've been checking the source code (MenuInflater.java,MenuBuilder.java..etc.,) for any clues but no luck yet :-(.

Can someone let me know is it doable thing?

Thanks